# Confused between if-then (→) and iff (↔)

Tags: propositional-calculus, logic-translation

Consider the following argument from my assignment.

> Tarzan will only be happy if his pet monkey comes home. The monkey will come home if it rains. It won't rain today. So Tarzan will be unhappy.

Let

- $H$ mean "Tarzan will be happy".
- $C$ mean "the monkey will come home".
- $R$ mean "it will rain today".

**Question:** Express the argument symbolically as a logical implication, using the symbol $\implies$.

Here’s the provided solution from the teacher.

$$(H \to C) \land (R \to C) \land \neg R \implies \neg H$$

I don’t understand why I can’t translate the first argument $(H \to C)$ as $(H \leftrightarrow  C)$ since Tarzan will **only be happy** if his monkey comes home.

Comment: There may be several other things that would make Tarzan unhappy even if his monkey came home. (I can work these problems only in English, not in symbols.)

Comment: This is why "iff" is an abbreviation for "if and only if" and not just an abbreviation for "only if".

Answer (score 6):

Just because the monkey is home, that doesn't automatically mean that Tarzan is happy. That's how "only if" is interpreted in conventional mathematical English. Tarzan can't be happy if the monkey is away, but when the monkey is there, Tarzan could be either happy or non-happy.

Comment: For example if Tarzan finds out that The Last Man on Earth got cancelled, he will be *very* unhappy.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think _unhappy_ is the right term to use in this context. Although happy and unhappy are commonly considered mutually exclusive, I don't believe they are complementary. Hence my use of the term "non-happy".

Comment: Arthur, yes, this is the difference between "being infinite" and "co-finite". One of these is stronger than the other. Being unhappy implies non-happy, but not the other way around. I just gave an example of a situation where you have a stronger property, which therefore implies the non-happiness.

Answer (score 2):

Think like this:

1) $\Rightarrow$ means *implies*, that is

It rains $\Rightarrow$ I take an umbrealla with me.

Observe that this is only in *one way* because the fact that I take an umbrella with me won't make it rain. So I cannot say

I take an umbrella $\Rightarrow$ It will rain.

2) An *if and only if* statement works in both ways

Raindrops are falling from the clouds $\iff$ It rains

Statements which have $\iff$ between them are called *equivalent* and are usually interchangeable.

Hope this helps clarify some things

Answer (score 1):

Sentences containing 'only if' are always tricky.

To make some sense of these, let's use a different use of 'only if':

"You can be a bachelor only if you are a male"

I think this one is a little easier to analyze:

We clearly have $B \rightarrow M$: if you are a bachelor, you have to be male.

Or, analyzed differently: the statement says that if you are not a male, then you cannot be a bachelor, which is $\neg M \rightarrow \neg B$. But by contraposiiton, that's equivalent to $B \rightarrow M$

OK, but do we also have $M \rightarrow B$ (and thus effectively $B \leftrightarrow M$?)

No! Just because you are a male does not make you a bachelor.

OK, and so it is with Tarzan and his pet monkey:

> Tarzan will only be happy if his pet monkey comes home

This clearly means that as long as his pet monkey is not coming home, Tarzan will not be happy, i.e. $\neg C \rightarrow \neg T$, which by Contraposition is equivalent to $T \rightarrow C$

OK, but does it also mean that Tarzan *will* be happy if his pet monkey *does* come home? Well, maybe Tarzan would only be happy if his pet monkey, while coming home, isn't bringing in any of his annoying friends. So no, just because his pet monkey comes home does not guarantee Tarzan to be happy so we don't have  $C \rightarrow T$.

Indeed, if we want to say that Tarzan is happy *exactly whenever* his pet money is coming home, we should say something like "Tarzan will only be happy if and only if his pet monkey comes home" .. which they didn't say.